# Can't boot into Windows 8 from Ubuntu boot screen on startup

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, windows-8

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 12.10 alongside Windows 8 on a separate partition. The installation went fine but now when I turn on the PC (Asus S200E) I get the Ubuntu boot screen asking for my OS selection.

Possible choices are:

- Ubuntu
- Ubuntu Advanced Settings
- Windows Recovery Environment
- Windows Launcher.

If I choose Ubuntu it works but if I choose Windows Launcher it comes up with `could not find command drivemap` and `invalid EFI file path` (from memory). However, I can get into Windows if I shut down the PC in Ubuntu with the physical power button (i.e. not the software power down) and then hold ESC when the Asus logo appears, to choose the boot option, and select the Windows 8 drive, by the way two Ubuntu drives come up here which was not expected.

Before, when I used the Windows installer for Ubuntu and it did not work (got loads of errors) there was a boot up screen that said "Do you want to boot Windows 8 or Ubuntu?" Where as that gone? And why can't I boot Windows from the Ubuntu boot screen?

Comment: tried `boot-repair` as mentioned here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI ?? wubi is not very much compatible with windows 8. Even they are considering dropping wubi support from 13.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair and install boot-repair using the instructions there. After that, open the application and click on recommended repair. This should repair it.  You can boot Windows through the boot options. Hold whatever key it tells you to hold for boot options. Then select UEFI OS. If you want to boot it through the grub menu, open the terminal using ctrl - alt - t and type

```
    sudo update-grub
```

Put in your password.
Grub should automatically detect it.

Comment: You're welcome! Now I need an answer to my question...

Comment: Boot-Repair automatically does the `sudo update-grub`, so re-doing it manually is not necessary. (but not harmful)